# Responsive video player

Tags: responsive-design, jwplayer, flowplayer

I need a video player for responsive layout website which is developed by using bootstrap. That means when i do re-size the screen or viewing the page in different size screens the player should be automatically fit to the screen.

I had tried with jwplayer and flowplayer but it didn't work.

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/forums/jw-player/setup-issues-and-embedding/24635/responsive-video-internet-explorer-100-widthheight

note: The player should be able to play the youtube videos....

Is there anyway to make jwplayer/flowplayer responsive?

Answer (score 6):

**Better version of Luka's answer**:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var $width = $("#holder").width();
    var $height = $width/1.5;
    jwplayer().resize($width,$height);
});
```

User the **resize** function from the JW Player API:

http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/29411/resizing-the-player

**Another solution**:

Check their Responsive Design Support documentation: http://www.longtailvideo.com/support/jw-player/32427/responsive-design-support

```
<div id="myElement"></div>
<script>
    jwplayer("myElement").setup({
        file: "/uploads/myVideo.mp4",
        image: "/uploads/myPoster.jpg",
        width: "100%",
        aspectratio: "12:5" // Set your image ratio here
    });
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

you can change by simple css style

```
/* Video small screen */
.video {
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 56.25%;
height: 0;
overflow: hidden;
}

.video iframe,  
.video object,  
.video embed {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 width: 100%;
 height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I am using jQuery for resizing. `#holder` is your div where movie is positioned (`#videocontainer`).
Structure:

```
<div id="holder">
    <div id="videocontainer"></div>
</div>
```

It takes `#holder` size and give it to `#videocontainer`. It works in ie9, ie8, ...

```
$(window).resize(function() {
    var $width = $("#holder").width();
    var $height = $width/1.5;
    jwplayer("videocontainer").setup({  
    flashplayer: "jwplayer/player.swf",
    file: "###.mp4",                            
    width: $width,
    height: $height,
    image: "###.jpg"
    });
});
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Try FitVids: http://fitvidsjs.com/

If you want to make jwPlayer responsive, try adding this to your CSS file:

```
#video-jwplayer_wrapper {
    position: relative;
    padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* 16:9 format */
    padding-top: 30px;
    height: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
}
#video-jwplayer_wrapper iframe, #video-jwplayer_wrapper object, #video-jwplayer_wrapper embed {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}
```

source: http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/css-elastic-videos

When calling jwplayer, you might also need to set width to 100%:

```
jwplayer("myElement").setup({
    width: 100%
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use javascript

```
 function sizing() {
        $('#player').css('width', $('#container').outerWidth());
        $('#player').css('height',$('#player').outerWidth() / 1.33);
    }

    $(document).ready(sizing);
    $(window).resize(sizing);
```

Don't forget to include jquery library and to change the aspect ration (1.33 is for 4:3, 1,77 is for 16:9).

Answer (score 0):

This work well for me
                        JW Player goes here

```
<script type="text/javascript">

                            if($( window ).width() <= 400){
                                 pl_width = 300;
                                 pl_heith = 150;
                            }else if($( window ).width() <= 600){
                                 pl_width = 500;
                                 pl_heith = 250;
                            }else{
                                pl_width = 700;
                                pl_heith = 350;
                            }
                            //alert(pl_width);
                            jwplayer("video_top").setup({

                                flashplayer: "<?php echo $player_path; ?>",

                                file: "<?php echo $your_file; ?>",
                                controlbar: "bottom",

                                height:pl_heith,

                                width:pl_width


                            });
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just use YouTube videos in your site and use the [FitVid.Js](http://fitvidsjs.com/) plugin to make it responsive.

Comment: The same answer goes regardless of what video player you want to use. You only need to update the options to include your particular video player name.