# How could I contain a child div that has a height auto -- Jwplayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jwplayer

When Jwplayer is initialized, they inject a class with the css of

```
.jwplayer.jw-flag-aspect-mode {
  height: auto !important;
}
```

My code is

```
<div style="height: 80vh; width: 100%">
  <div style="height: 90%; width: 100%;>
    <div style="height: 100%; width: 100%;>
      <!-- JwPlayer here -->
      <div id="sample-video"></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div style="height: 10%; width: 100%;>
    <!-- actions bar here -->
  </div>
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
  //psuedo code
  jwplayer('#sample-video").setup({
    sources: sources,
    autostart:true,
    width: '100%'
  });
</script>
```

Problem is that when jwplayer injects their own css, they override the heights even if I set it manually inline or through their setup with the above mentioned class.

[image]

That in turn would cause the video player to disregard the parent and overflow below. If I can change height: auto to height: 100%;, then my expected behaviour is correct.

I've tried every answer in [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12423981/responsive-video-player) and all of them listed on jwplayer's support site.

Comment: It might mean something that `.jw-flag-aspect-mode` class gets added. Have you tried missing with the aspectratio, height, or stretching configuration options outlined in the [docs](https://developer.jwplayer.com/jw-player/docs/developer-guide/customization/configuration-reference/#setup)?

Comment: I have tried the combinations of width height and aspectratio. I figured why they never mention the height in the docs is because they override it anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting the jwplayer setup options of height works. It will maintain 100% if explicitly set to do so.

```
jwplayer('div').setup({
    height: 100%,
    width: 100%
});
```

Run <del>this Snippet</del> the Plunker in full display and resize the window, it is fully responsive and will not exceed the height of **it's container**.

[**PLUNKER**](http://plnkr.co/edit/P7og09fZLzOX6RBkqLmM?p=preview)

<del>##SNIPPET</del>

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>JW Auto Height</title>
<script src="http://p.jwpcdn.com/6/12/jwplayer.js?"></script>
<style></style>
</head>

<body>
<!-- div is 80% height of this screen -->
<div style="height: 80vh; width: 100%; outline: 5px dotted red;">
  <!-- section is 90% height of div -->
  <section style="height: 90%; width: 100%; outline: 3px dashed blue;">
    <!-- main is 100% height of section -->
    <main style="height: 100%; width: 100%; outline: 1px solid black;">
     <!-- jw is 100% height of main -->
      <div id="jw"></div>
      
    </main>
  </section>
  <!-- nav is 10% height of div -->
  <nav style="height: 10%; width: 100%; outline: 2px solid grey; background: grey"></nav>
</div>
<div style="margin: 30px auto;">This is 20% of the screen's height</div>
<script>
//Real code

jwplayer("jw").setup({ 
 sources: [{
  file: "http://glvid.s3.amazonaws.com/jwp/test/3clox.mp4"
 }], 
  width: "100%",  
  height: "100%"  
});  



</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: It turns out one of the parent divs that the video was contained in, just needed a height: 100%; ! Thanks!

Comment: Your welcome, sir. If you have layout problems, I find it easier to fix things by using `outline`. It's like `border` but it doesn't take up any space which is perfect for debugging layouts.

Answer (score 1):

since that looks more like an answer than a comment:

---

you may not mind `height:auto!important` by using as well:

```
.jwplayer.jw-flag-aspect-mode {
    min-height:100%;
    max-height:100%;
}
```

where you set the values to constrain the desired fixed or not fixed height value(s) of your element